# What happens when short interest exceeds outstanding shares

Tags: shorting-securities

Let us say there are 100 outstanding shares of company X held by investor A. Investor B comes in, borrows these 100 shares and short sells them to investor C.

Which means, outstanding shares=100, short interest =100.

Investor B borrows these 100 shares again from C and short sells them to investor D.

So now, short interest is 200 and outstanding shares is 100.

In this case, how can B fulfill his obligation to return the 100 shares to A and 100 shares to C? He can only buy 100 shares but he is short 200 shares

Comment: D and C are both long 100 each. B can buy from both to close the positions.

Comment: Thanks. I am confused between your answer and mike Scott answer. They both seem correct, but they aren't the same.

Comment: I can't source it but I believe that borrowed shares cannot be loaned out again.  IOW, B can borrow from A and sell to C but C cannot loan those shares out for another short sell.  If that were allowed, short sellers would have an infinite supply of shares to short.

Comment: Then hedge fund owners get very angry on national TV and collude with stock brokers to avoid the situation. (Future readers: Google 'wallstreetbets gamestop short squeeze robinhood')

Answer (score 2):

It's called a [short squeeze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_squeeze), and for example happened to Volkswagen in 2008. It's a known hazard of short selling, especially in thinly traded stocks. The answer is that investor D can charge investor B whatever he wants for the shares, since investor B has to have them.

Comment: Even if investor D charges a lot, he can only sell 100 shares, whereas B( not A) needs to buy back 200 shares,not 100.

Comment: Thanks, have corrected the error, And yes, so assuming investor B returns them to investor A, he then has to buy them back again (at whatever price investor A cares to charge) so as to return them to investor C.